# How to change the formula to inverse the results?

Tags: geometry, angle

I have the following formula:
[image]

where *i* and *j* are both angles between 0° and 360° (they are essentialy vectors with this angle). The formula is inteded to provide a measure on how parallel or orthogonal the two vectors are to oneanother. The output is between 0° and 45°.

However, the way the formula is written it provides me 0° if i and j are 45° different from oneanother and it calulates 45 when the difference of the angle is 0 (or a multiple of 90).

Is there an easy math trick to ensure the output is what is intuitively excepted? i.e. difference in angle = formula output?

Comment: I am not sure I get the question. If you wanted "formula output=difference in angles", wouldn't the formula be simply $|i-j|$?

Comment: sadly no, because the difference of the angle has to be between 0 and 45. This is because orthogonal vectors and paralell vectors are both assumed to have an angle of 0.  Also, vector pairs with angle 0 and 180 are supposed to give 0 as output (my formula calculates 45 instead of 0).

Comment: So just take $45-(your formula)$ ? I would avoid the cosines and do $45-|(|i-j| \bmod 90)-45|$.